# Create advertising folder on usb stick

Tags: windows, usb, fat32, protected

I want create advertising folder on USB stick. 
Therefore I want to unable user from removing it. even if they format it.

It is possible?

Comment: Nope. There will always be a way to wipe the disc

Comment: Short answer: not possible, at least with an off-the-shelf stick.

Comment: Please check this question. http://superuser.com/questions/934860/can-i-create-usb-3-0-flash-drive-with-undeletable-files. Yes its possible but also huge YMMV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a regular USB flash drive: No. Not possible.

On custom (expensive!) hardware: Yes. See the other post about that here on [su].